# Using Linq to do a Contains with multiple values

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I have a medication table that I'm looking for certain drug names, but I need to search for multiple names.  Here is where I currently am with it.

```
string[] names = new string[2];
names[0] = "apixaban";
names[1] = "desirudin";

var meds = (from m in Medications where names.Any(m.BrandName.Contains) || names.Any(m.GenericName.Contains) select m);
```

What I have isn't working, and I'm currently stuck.  I know I'm close, but I can't quite figure out what's wrong.

**EDIT**

For clarification, if the name I'm searching for is desirudin, then the BrandName or Generic name will be longer, so I have to have the contains on the field in the database.

**EDIT 2**
Here is the error I recieve.

```
Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Any'.
```

Here is what I finally ended up with

```
var meds = (from m in db.AdmissionMedications where 
(names.Any(n => m.BrandName.Contains(n)) || names.Any(n => m.GenericName.Contains(n))
) select m);
```

Comment: Please post the error message if you get one, or the fact that it runs without returning results

Comment: You need to use a lambda in the `Any()` method, like in my answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Maybe somthing like

C# Linq:

```
var meds = (from m in Medications 
            where names.Any(name => name.Equals(m.BrandName) || m.GenericName.Contains(name)) 
            select m);
```

Extension methods:

```
List<Medication> meds = Medications
    .Where( med =>
        names.Any( name =>
            name.Equals( med.BrandName ) || med.GenericName.Contains( name )
        )
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Jhorra, your query seems fine then. Could you provide some sample data? And what exactly is not working with your query?

Comment: Updated my answer with what i think you need

Comment: Yours came the closest to what I was looking for.  I had to tweak it, but it was on the right track and got me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a join between the medication table and the names array.

```
var query = from m in Medications
            from n in in names
            where m.BrandNames.Any(bn => bn.Contains(n)) || m.GenericNames.Any(gn => gn.Contains(n))
            select m;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to try:

```
var query = Medications.Where(m => names.Contains(m.BrandName) || names.Contains(m.GenericName));
```

Comment: it will compare only single value. what if i need to compare both value at time in and condition.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your right:

```
var meds = Medications.Where(m => names.Contains(m.BrandName) || names.Contains(m.GenericName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = (from c in Reports where c.HKPlanningQty == xi select c).Select(u=>new {Style=u.Style,QTN=u.HKPlanningQty}).OrderBy(u =>u.Style ).Where(v=>v.Style.Contains("44")||v.Style.Contains("58"));
```