# C# LINQ Contains method with two clauses

Tags: c#, linq, contains

What is the best practice way to use two clauses in LINQ Contains method..

Title is string

**This is my If statement :**

```
if (oWeb.ParentWeb.Title.Contains("Ricky") || oWeb.ParentWeb.Title.Contains("John"))
```

**I need solution like this :**

```
 if (oWeb.ParentWeb.Title.Contains("Ricky", "John"))
```

Comment: you're looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235661/using-linq-to-do-a-contains-with-multiple-values ?

Comment: Title is string. YES

Comment: If you need a method that does that then write a method that does that.  What problems are you having writing such a method?

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL?  i.e. Do you really need to use LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Title` is `string` this actually has nothing to do with LINQ as the used `Contains` method is an instance method of `string`.

Assuming you have more strings to check, you can do something like that:

```
var strings = new[] {"Ricky", "John"};
if (strings.Any(oWeb.ParentWeb.Title.Contains))
    // do something
```

But [roryap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38876432/5528593)'s answer using a regex seems preferable (as long as the number of strings to check is not too big).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think LINQ is the best option for that.  Why not use regular expressions?

```
Regex.IsMatch(oWeb.ParentWeb.Title, "ricky|john", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Better idea than LINQ if the number of strings to check is not too big (don't know if OP may have more than "ricky" and "john").

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` takes only one parameter, so you cannot do it this way.

You can make an array of items, and check containment with it:

```
var titles = new[] {"Ricky", "John"};
if (titles.Any(t => oWeb.ParentWeb.Title.Contains(t))) {
    ...
}
```